# Trouble with using grep to find a string in a text file

Tags: bash, shell

User enters in an email. I use grep to check if the email already exists within a specific file.

Here's the part of the code that I'm having trouble with

```
$word = [user input (email) ]
legit = [boolean that is used for something else. No problem with that here]
```

I'm new. Help me kindly please.

```
if [[ grep -f "$word" "/root/Desktop/Dan/Logs/member-name-file" "$variable.txt" ]]
            then
                echo "Email already exists on requested List**"
                legit=false
            else
                echo "Email added onto list**"
                legit=true
            fi
```

Comment: You are trying to read the pattern to match from a file named after the user's input. You want `-e` instead of `-f`. Also, what is `$variable`?

Comment: $variable is my "variable" for TIMESTAMP

Comment: Is that timestamp part of filename? If so, it should be `"…/member-name-file$variable.txt"`, otherwise grep will look at `…/member-name-file"` and at `$variable.txt` as different files.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
if [[ grep -f "$word" "/root/Desktop/Dan/Logs/member-name-file" "$variable.txt" ]]
```

You can do:

```
if grep -q "$word" "/root/Desktop/Dan/Logs/member-name-file"
```